# How can I ensure a function/method param is of a certian type?

Tags: javascript

Is it possible to ensure that a function/method paramater is of a certain type?

For example I have a simple Character class that accepts an optional `Health` object. Is it possible to check that the param is infact of type `Health`? I wouldn't want the consumer to pass in an integer when the application expects a `Health` object.

```
let Character = function(health) {
    if(typeof health === 'undefined')
        this.health = new Health(100);
    else
        this.health = health;
};

Character.prototype.hit = function(hitPoints) {
    this.health.subtract(hitPoints);
};
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this particular case, yes, you have two options:

1. `instanceof`:

   ```
   if (health instanceof Health) {
       // It's a Health object *OR* a derivative of one
   }
   ```

   Technically, what `instanceof` checks is that the object `Health.prototype` refers to is in `health`'s prototype chain.
2. Check `constructor`

   ```
   if (health.constructor === Health) {
       // Its `constructor` is `Health`, which usually (but not necessarily)
       // means it was constructed via Health
   }
   ```

   Note that this is easy to fake: `let a = {}; a.constructor = Health;`

Normally you'd probably want to reach for the former, because A) It allows for subtypes of `Health`, and B) When doing inheritance hierarchies with ES5 and earlier syntax, a **lot** of people forget to fix `constructor` and it ends up pointing to the wrong function.

Example in ES5 syntax:

```js
var Health = function() {
};

var PhysicalHealth = function() {
  Health.call(this);
};
PhysicalHealth.prototype = Object.create(Health.prototype);
PhysicalHealth.prototype.constructor = PhysicalHealth;

var h = new PhysicalHealth();
log(h instanceof Health);     // true
log(h.constructor == Health); // false

function log(msg) {
  var p = document.createElement('p');
  p.appendChild(document.createTextNode(msg));
  document.body.appendChild(p);
}
```

Or using ES2015 (ES6):

```js
class Health {
}

class PhysicalHealth extends Health {
}

let h = new PhysicalHealth();
log(h instanceof Health);     // true
log(h.constructor == Health); // false

function log(msg) {
  let p = document.createElement('p');
  p.appendChild(document.createTextNode(msg));
  document.body.appendChild(p);
}
```

Comment: I think it's time to start using ES6. That looks much better and looks similar to OOP in other languages I'm used to. Thanks. For a moment I thought you was the legendary TJ from the nodejs world.

Comment: @BugHunterUK: Nope, just little old me. :-) Yeah, ES2015 is a huge advance on ES5 on multiple fronts. And transpilers are so good these days we don't even have to wait for browser support. (I should mention that you were already relying on an ES2015 feature: `let`.)

Answer (score 0):

Short way of doing...

`let character = function(health) {
    this.health = (health instanceof Health) ? health : new Health(100);
}`